# grunt-contrib-copy exclude a list of files

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, copy

I use grunt and grunt-contrib-copy;
My goal: I want to copy all files inside a folder to another folder *except a configurable list of files*

```
  copy: {
    files: [{
     expand:true, 
     cwd: './dist/Assets/',
     src: [
      '**/*',
      '!{Css,Images}/**/*',
      '!Js/{filetoexlude1.js,filetoexclude2.js}'  
      ], 
    filter: 'isFile',    
    dest:'./deploy/Assets/'
}]  
}
```

As I don't want to write the list of files inside the task, I wrote a json file called files.json with this content:

```
{  
"filestoexcludefromcopy":[
"filetoexclude1.js",
"filetoexclude2.js"
]
}
```

Inside the Gruntfile.js:

```
filestoexcludefromcopy: grunt.file.readJSON('files.json').filestoexcludefromcopy,
```

and modified my task:

```
  copy: {
files: [{
  expand:true, 
  cwd: './dist/Assets/',
  src: [
    '**/*',
    '!{Css,Images}/**/*',
    '!Js/{<%= filestoexcludefromcopy%>}'  
    ], 
  filter: 'isFile',    
  dest:'./deploy/Assets/'
}]  
}
```

that works well... except when inside the files.json there is only one file... could someone help me to configure the task correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Grunt seems to process the [template](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) differently when the `length` of the `filestoexcludefromcopy` array is one.

To avoid this quirk you can push an empty item onto the `filestoexcludefromcopy` array when its `length` is only one.

Whilst this is not particularly elegant - it works successfully.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
filestoexcludefromcopy: (function() {
    var files = grunt.file.readJSON('files.json').filestoexcludefromcopy;
    if (files.length === 1) {
        files.push(''); // Ensures files array length is greater than 1.
    }
    return files;
}()),

copy: {
    foo: { // Added a target
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: './dist/Assets/',
            src: [
                '**/*',
                '!{Css,Images}/**/*',
                '!Js/{<%= filestoexcludefromcopy%>}'
            ],
            filter: 'isFile',
            dest: './deploy/Assets/'
        }]
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer**

Remove the curly braces `{}` from the template. I.e. Change this:

```js
'!Js/{<%= filestoexcludefromcopy%>}'
```

to this:

```js
'!Js/<%= filestoexcludefromcopy%>'
```

Note: In the gist below a [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) was also added to the `copy` Task.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
//...
filestoexcludefromcopy: grunt.file.readJSON('files.json').filestoexcludefromcopy,

copy: {
    foo: { // Add a Target to the 'copy' Task
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: './dist/Assets/',
            src: [
                '**/*',
                '!{Css,Images}/**/*',
                '!Js/<%= filestoexcludefromcopy%>' // Remove the curly braces.
            ],
            filter: 'isFile',
            dest: './deploy/Assets/'
        }]
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but removing the curly braces simply copies all the files; the files listed in json are completely ignored

Comment: Interesting, it worked successfully here on Mac OS...Which platform/OS are you using?

Comment: I tried with both Windows and MacOSX, without success.
It will work in this way:

`src: [  '**/*',  '!{Css,Images}/**/*',  '<%= files.filestoexcludefromcopy%>' ],`
and writing the json file in this way:
`"filestoexcludefromcopy":[ "!Js/file1.js", "!Js/file2.js" ]`
But I was hoping for a cleaner syntax

Comment: Updated answer... Yes, it seems that `grunt` processes the template differently when the `length` of the `filestoexcludefromcopy` array is only one - which is rather odd! Whilst this revised solution is also not particularly elegant it will allow you to keep your original `.json` file syntax.